How to implement memory sharing between .NET services?
I am developing a .NET application that consists of multiple services needing to share data efficiently. I am exploring various methods to achieve this, and I am seeking advice on the best approach to take.
Requirements:
**Shared DbContext:
All services should use the same DbContext instance to ensure consistency and avoid issues related to multiple contexts.
Thread Safety:
The solution must be thread-safe as the services might be accessed concurrently.
Scalability:
The solution should scale as the application grows and more services are added.
Performance:
The solution should not introduce significant performance overhead.

I have looked into several methods, including:

Memory-Mapped Files:
Useful for high-performance inter-process communication but seems complex for scaling across multiple services.
Named Pipes:
Provides a way for processes to communicate but seems limited in scalability.
RabbitMQ:
An option for decoupled and asynchronous communication, but I'm not sure if it's the best fit for memory sharing.

If the services don't share a process, sharing a DbContext (or any kind of object) is simply not possible, separate processes means separate instances. By the way, why is that even a requirement?

thanks @Alejandro because every sevice loads DBContrext.

From my comprehension, rabbitmq is a good choice for decoupling services. Redis for sharing data usually has good performances. Whether complex or limited mainly depends on how you manage the structure.

Thanks @FengzhiZhou but I want share dbcontext, I can or not, it is best practice or not

According to my research, you cannot do it, and it is not a good choice, as thread safety cannot be ensured and it will be hard to manage the  lifetime is asp.net core.

@FengzhiZhou I gree with you, so what I can do ?

For shared data, implement Redis, use managed Redis services like AWS ElastiCache or Azure Redis Cache for easier scaling and management.
